# Set Selected Cell on load NSTableViewCell

Tags: swift, macos, selection, nstableview

Iv got a mac application that uses a table view on the left side of the window as the navigation, and then another table view on the right that shows the relevant information.

I do this by just checking what cell is selected on the left table view and use that to update the information on the right.

The problem is when the table views load they dont have a row selected, the selected row shows up as -1 (AKA nothing) i need the table view to have a row selected when the view loads, not just after someone selects it. Kinda like the finder window, when you open the application it has a row already selected.

And no i dont want to just change the background color of the cell so it looks selected when the app opens, because that wont fix the -1 problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cans select a row programmatically using the  API on NSTableView:

```
func selectRowIndexes(_ indexes: NSIndexSet,
 byExtendingSelection extend: Bool)
```

Let us say, you want to pre select the 0th row, then you can need to call the above API as in viewDidLoad method:

```
tableView. selectRowIndexes(NSIndexSet(index:0) byExtendingSelection:NO)
```